# Selecting a option with jquery and also has a onchange() in the select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select VISA in this selection, but it won't work. I've tried almost everything.

```
$('#creditcard_cctype option[value="VISA"]').click();
$('#creditcard_cctype').val("VISA");
$('#creditcard_cctype option[value="VISA"]').prop("selected", true);
$('#creditcard_cctype option[value="VISA"]').attr("selected", true);
$('#creditcard_cctype option[value="VISA"]').cttr("selected", "selected");
```

The problem is that the updateCreditCardType() function changes around the html file so I can obtain the CCV option. It just isn't selecting.

```
<select name="creditcard_cctype" id="creditcard_cctype" onchange="updateCreditCardType()" class="Field250">
    <option value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
    <option id="CCType_AMEX" class=" requiresCVV2" value="AMEX">American Express</option>
    <option id="CCType_DISCOVER" class=" requiresCVV2" value="DISCOVER">Discover</option>
    <option id="CCType_MC" class=" requiresCVV2" value="MC">Mastercard</option>
    <option id="CCType_VISA" class=" requiresCVV2" value="VISA">Visa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you post  `updateCreditCardType` function too

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the `change` event to force the HTML-bound `onchange` handler to fire.

```
$('#creditcard_cctype').val('VISA').trigger('change');
```

jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c3sqhrma/

Comment: @CholeaOum If it doesn't work for you, then you'll need to provide more information about your problem. Ideally, you should build a jsFiddle demo that reproduces your problem. Triggering the change event does work (as demonstrated in my jsFiddle), so without further information about your problem, it's impossible for us to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this to set the value once the document is ready

```
$('#creditcard_cctype').val('VISA');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c3sqhrma/2/

Comment: you need to explain clearly or post the method by which it is changed and when you need it's value?